# How do I access the name_with_location_descriptor field on the /page endpoint on the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) Graph API Reference has a field named `name_with_location_descriptor`, which is defined as:

> The name of the Page with its location and/or global brand descriptor

and has a tooltip which states:

> This field is only accessible in v2.2 or later

However, I can't make that field appear on any Pages I try, using both v2.2 and v2.3. What's the secret for making this field show up? (And while we're at it, what should I expect to find in that field?)

---

To provide some more information, the field doesn't even appear to be available on the root `/<page-id>` endpoint but only as a child node in `global_brand_children`. Here's a [Graph API explorer link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=coca-cola%3Ffields%3Dglobal_brand_children%7Bname%2Cname_with_location_descriptor%2Clocation%2Ccurrent_location%7D&version=v2.3&) showing that the field is available (albeit grayed out) for this page, which has global brand children. I've also tried toggling the version to v2.2 with no change.

Comment: Bug I suppose - Report it , https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/ , but very interesting find! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well possibly not a bug like I thought it was, looks like it's the page descriptor name i.e. name of the page with the store location that needs to be filled out while using the `facebook locations` features while registering a particular location for a child of your brand page. Essentially a concat of name and location. Don't see a field separately allocated to fill this out on the page, but can be quickly validated if you have a brand and use facebook locations, because I haven't found a page yet that has different values for `name` field and the `name_with_location_descriptor field`. If the field isn't filled in, then it wouldn't show up.

For instance here's the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=322605374498798%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cname_with_location_descriptor%2Clocation%2Ccurrent_location&version=v2.3&) and result for Cafe coffee day, a popular brand in India, for a Bangalore location

```
{
  "name": "Cafe Coffee Day Square", 
  "name_with_location_descriptor": "Cafe Coffee Day Square", 
  "location": {
    "city": "Bangalore", 
    "country": "India", 
    "latitude": 12.971819331327, 
    "longitude": 77.594207611099, 
    "street": "Cafe Coffee Day Square , 193926289498", 
    "zip": "560001"
  }, 
  "id": "322605374498798"
}
```

And another for a different location, but still in Bangalore

```
{
  "name": "Cafe Coffee Day - BTM Layout", 
  "name_with_location_descriptor": "Cafe Coffee Day - BTM Layout", 
  "location": {
    "city": "Bangalore", 
    "country": "India", 
    "latitude": 12.91400869993, 
    "longitude": 77.609964412192, 
    "street": "Cafe Coffee Day - BTM Layout , 193926289498", 
    "zip": "560068"
  }, 
  "id": "115977698546185"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I [submitted a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/792236434193071/) and Facebook's response basically made it clear that I'm expecting the wrong data out of this field. I thought it related to the global brand pages, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not been able to directly validate this information yet, it is my understanding that `name_with_location_descriptor`is literally the `name` field with the `store_location_descriptor` appended to it. Facebook's documentation states:

> Location descriptor for this store. This will appear after the Page
>   name and should only be used if the location has a special location
>   that's not clear from its city or street address. e.g. if it's inside
>   a shopping mall or if it's best identified by its neighborhood.

So, in the example above, if the `name` was "Cafe Coffee" and the `store_location_descriptor` was "Day Square", then it is my understanding that one would see something like:

```
{
  "name": "Cafe Coffee", 
  "store_location_descriptor": "Day Square",
  "name_with_location_descriptor": "Cafe Coffee (Day Square)",
  ...
}
```

If I can find an example from the API, I'll post it but the folks a ReShiftMedia have a pretty good [blog post](https://www.reshiftmedia.com/facebook-locations-updated-with-name-reviews-changes/) that explains how Facebook is trying to lock down the `name` field so all locations of the same store have the same name.